# Material-UI: AppBar => FlatButton Text unstyled if not defined directly

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Okay, what I want to do is this: I want my AppBar to have a FlatButton with the label "Login". This label should change to "Logout" for obvious reasons.

Now, when I define the AppBar like this then I get the proper styling:

[image]

and the code like this:

```
let App = React.createClass({
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <AppBar
                    title="Foobar"
                    iconElementRight={<FlatButton>Login</FlatButton>}
                />
                <div className="LandingPage">
                    {this.props.children}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

However, this does not allow me to change the text. Which is why I pulled the FlatButton out into an extra component like this:

```
let UserName = React.createClass({
    render(){
        return(
            <FlatButton>Login</FlatButton>
        )
    }
});

let App = React.createClass({
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <AppBar
                    title="Foobar"
                    iconElementRight={<UserName />}
                />
                <div className="LandingPage">
                    {this.props.children}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

What I get as a result is this:

[image]

So, what do I have to do differently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the `material-ui` source code of `app-bar.jsx`, it checks the display name of the passed component then based on that, applies the needed styles. This code specifically

```
// app-bar.jsx

if (iconElementRight) {
  switch (iconElementRight.type.displayName) {
    case 'IconMenu':
    case 'IconButton':
      iconElementRight = React.cloneElement(iconElementRight, {
        iconStyle: this.mergeStyles(styles.iconButton.iconStyle, iconElementRight.props.iconStyle),
      });
      break;

    case 'FlatButton':
      iconElementRight = React.cloneElement(iconElementRight, {
        style: this.mergeStyles(styles.flatButton, iconElementRight.props.style),
      });
      break;
  }

// ...
```

What you have to do is add the `FlatButton` to your `UserName` like this

```
let UserName = React.createClass({
  displayName: 'FlatButton',
  render() {
    return <FlatButton style={this.props.style} >Login</FlatButton>;
  },
});
```

and lastly, `this.props.style` is injected to the `UserName` and you need to pass it on `<FlatButton />` to apply the styles.